# Delay closing of bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to modify the behavior of the bootstrap dropdown. First, I wanted to prevent the dropdown from closing when you click elsewhere on the page. I did that with this code:

```
$('#filters').on({
    "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { this.closable = false; },
    "click":             function() { this.closable = true; },
    "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { return this.closable; }
});
```

Now, I want to delay the closing of the dropdown, when you click a link inside it. I want to do this because the dropdown closes immediately when you click the link, before you've actually left the page and loaded the new one.

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7n7rhtLd/5/) of what I have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7n7rhtLd/6/)**

I would like to suggest you 2 things:

> - add `eventlisteners` on `.btn-group` instead of `#filters` as its
>     easy enough to check which `dropdown` was clicked
> - Add the required animations to `click` event instead

So according to above suggestions code would go as below:

```
$('.btn-group').on({
    "shown.bs.dropdown": function () {
        this.closable = false;
    },
    "click": function () {
        this.closable = true;
            if(!$(this).hasClass('open'))
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideToggle();
            else
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(600).slideToggle();

    },
    "hide.bs.dropdown": function () {
        return this.closable;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE :**

Based on your comment, I hope this is what you would desire to achieve:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7n7rhtLd/29/)**

```
$('.btn-group').on({
    "shown.bs.dropdown": function () {
        this.closable = false;
    },
        "click": function () {
            this.closable = true;
            $('.btn-group').not($(this)).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp();//Close all the dropdowns except this
            if(!$(this).hasClass('open'))
            {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideToggle();//open only this dropdown
                $('.btn-group').not($(this)).removeClass('open'); //remove the focus effect from other dropdowns
            }
            else
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(600).slideToggle();

    },
        "hide.bs.dropdown": function () {
        return this.closable;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Your example does accomplish the delay, however it breaks the ability to close one dropdown when you've clicked another. If you look at my fiddle, you'll see the how the other dropdowns close when you click another -- but they don't close if you click elsewhere on the page. I'd like to retain that behavior. Can that be done?

Comment: yea!! That is achievable!! give me a moment!!

Comment: @Lindsay.. Updated the answer!! Kindly check!!

Comment: Thank you! It's almost right, but when you click a link inside the dropdown (like "Action"), it quickly closes and then reopens again. That's the part where I'd like to add the delay. I added a delay to your "close all dropdowns" line (http://jsfiddle.net/7n7rhtLd/28/), but that adds the delay everyhwere, and I'd like the delay only to happen when you a click a link inside the dropdown.

Comment: @Lindsay Updated the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7n7rhtLd/29/)**. Check and let me know!!

Comment: Anytime.. :) Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you have to hack the normal bootstrap dropdown event sequence a bit, but you could use the event with an if/else to trigger the delay + slideUp() only if the this.closable is true. Then, since you're not able to "return true" on the hide.bs.dropdown event, you have to remove the 'open' class and then trigger the 'show()' yourself the next time you click the dropdown... like this:

Here's a fiddle with one working dropdown - you'll have to make unique ID's for each dropdown if you have multiples, and then probably use the event.target.[something] to identify the correct dropdown to toggle...

http://jsfiddle.net/yp44tt9e/2/

```
$('#filters').on({
    "show.bs.dropdown": function() {
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').show();
    },
    "shown.bs.dropdown": function () {
        this.closable = false;
    },
        "click": function () {
        this.closable = true;
    },
        "hide.bs.dropdown": function (e){
            if(this.closable){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu')
                    .first()
                    .stop(true, true)
                    .delay(600)
                    .slideUp('slow', function(){
                        $('.btn-group').removeClass('open');
                    });
             }else{
                return this.closable;
             }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it won't work for me to give unique IDs to each dropdown, as this is in wordpress and the menus will be changing frequently.